# Authentication token to only apply to one id

Tags: python, authentication, flask, restful-authentication

I am using this tutorial to incorporate `authentication` into my `app`: http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/restful-authentication-with-flask

At the moment I have the following `route`:

```
@app.route('/checkin/venue/<int:venue_id>', methods = ['POST'])
@auth.login_required
```

My `verify_password` function is quite similar to that specified in the tutorial except I am accessing my own `db`.

The issue is that when I generate a `token`, it can be used across multiple `venue_id`'s even though the `token` was generated using the credentials of a single`venue`.

Is there a way that I could pass the `venue_id` variable to the function `verify_password(email_or_token, password)` so when I call `verify_auth_token` I will be able to check that the `venue_id` encoded in the token actually corresponds to that made in the call:

```
@app.route('/checkin/venue/<int:venue_id>', methods = ['POST'])
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Put the id into [`session`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.session).

Comment: Thanks @Celeo . However if control is handed to the `verify_password` function as soon as `/checkin/venue/<int:venue_id>` is called, when should I put the `id` in `session`? Sorry if I've misunderstood.

Comment: Why not add `venue_id` as another parameter to `verify_password`?

Comment: @dirn The two parameters for `verify_password` come from the parameters specified in the `HTTP Authentication header` so I don't think there is a way to add another parameter to it?

Comment: Based on the version in the tutorial, you could add it as a filter to the SQLAlchemy query in the method that verifies the token.

Comment: @dirn I need the `venue_id` specified in `/checkin/venue/<int:venue_id>` to check against the `venue_id` embedded within the `token`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say this explicitly, but I assume you have the `venue_id` in the token, correct? If not, you should add it. The token can store any data you want so add the `venue_id` there in addition to the `user_id`.

So what you need is to compare the `venue_id` given in your request URL against the one in the token. And this is easy to do, since you can access the venue id in your URL as `request.view_args['venue_id']`.

So assuming you followed the design in my tutorial, you now have a `User.verify_auth_token(token)` method that decodes the token and verifies it. You can add an argument to this method that is the `venue_id`, and incorporate that verification in the logic of that method.

Then in your `verify_password` callback you can do something like this:

```
@auth.verify_password
def verify_password(token, password):
    user = User.verify_auth_token(token, request.view_args.get('venue_id', 0))
    if not user:
        return False
    g.user = user
    return True
```

Note that I chose a default of 0 for the case of a request that does not include a `venue_id` argument. This is just to avoid a crash. In your verification function you can choose to accept a `venue_id` of 0 as meaning that this request works for all venues, so in that case you skip the check on the venue.

Hope this helps!